# Output voltage of LC circuit?

Tags: radio, passive-filter

This figure is a crystal radio reciever and there is no active element involved in it.

LC filter is passive. Then how one can know that what output voltage LC circuit is offering to the diode and earphones?

Can the output voltage from LC circuit be found by using a multimeter/voltmeter or there is any other way to find the output voltage from LC circuit?

[image]

Comment: Where is the crystal?

Comment: @Marko, A "Crystal" detector is the old (really old) name for a diode (when it was actually made from a crystal chunk of Galena). So a radio design made from this type of component was called a Crystal Radio.

Comment: @Nedd I see now. Alex: you do need a small cap after the diode, the earphones shall be very high impedance. You can measure with V-meter.

Comment: *Can the output voltage from LC circuit be found by using a multimeter/voltmeter or there is any other way to find the output voltage from LC circuit?* - use an oscilloscope.

Comment: @Andy aka so oscilloscope can give us voltage fed to the diode and the earphone from the LC circuit?

Comment: That's precisely what o-scopes do best.

Comment: The "crystal" was the cat's whisker galena detector, but (unrelated) the [typical earpiece](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/Crystal_Earpiece.jpg/1280px-Crystal_Earpiece.jpg)  was also called a "crystal" earpiece. Today we'd probably call it a piezoelectric earpiece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This discussion assumes the circuit is used to receive medium-frequency AM broadcast band.

---

Since there are **no active elements** in this circuit, the only RF power available comes from the **antenna**, and possibly from the **earth** connection wire too.
Very little power is available: matching impedances with inductance and/or capacitance is essential to delivering audible power to headphones. The diode is the element that generates **audio power** from the available **RF power**. Causing a good deal of headphone audio current to flow is the goal.

Measuring voltages at either of the two nodes in this circuit (with respect to the third node **earth**, which is assumed as zero volts) requires knowledge of the circuit impedance at that node.
The diode efficiency at converting RF to audio is helped by having a high RF voltage at the antenna node. This is helped by the tuned LC resonator, which maximizes its impedance at one particular RF frequency. The antenna is often shown as a simple wire, but it usually adds a capacitive reactance, and small series resistance to this resonator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8WyyT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this simple circuit, power transfer is aided by keeping impedances at **NODE1** and at **NODE2** high. High-impedance headphones are rare today, but more common decades ago. Low impedance headphones (or speaker) generally give poor results because *impedance-matching* is not optimal.
Note that both audio current and RF current flow through L1.

TLDR:
We usually assume that **NODE3** is always at zero volts for both RF and audio. Many folks omit this connection, and get disappointing results due to the whole circuit floating...little RF power is delivered to the LC resonator. **NODE3** must be grounded in an effort to produce RF currents in the LC resonator.

Measuring voltages at NODE1 or NODE2 with a grounded oscilloscope might yield respectable voltages, but when the oscilloscope is disconnected, less audio is heard (because the ground is now missing).

Measuring audio voltages from **NODE2** to **NODE3** with a multimeter might give some indication provided a good earth ground is connected to **NODE3** (very few multimeters include their own ground connection). A digital multimeter often gives about three readings-per-second, and these numbers might jump about randomly, indicating audio voltage or current.

Comment: Can this circuit diagram with these values be made on a bread board? Will it work on breadboard? That was really a very nice answer. Thanks alot.

Comment: For the AM broadcast band, a breadboard is fine. The inductor value is a problem, because the value you choose depends on the antenna electrical characteristics. The antenna adds capacitance - when combined with the variable capacitor on your breadboard, and the inductor, resonant frequency can change. Headphone impedance should be high - I've used 4000-ohm headphones, and 2000-ohm headphones with only a diode in parallel successfully (loud audio). More common 32-ohm headphones or 8-ohm speaker give poor results.

Comment: "The antenna adds capacitance - when combined with the variable capacitor on your breadboard, and the inductor, resonant frequency can change." Can this problem be fixed?

Comment: Alex, unless your antenna wire is *really long*, it will add capacitance, and it will provide more signal power too. If you *really* want good signal strength, impedance-match your antenna to the LC resonator on your breadboard. Matching impedance isn't easy, because both your antenna's impedance, and ground impedance are unknown....it is an advanced project taken on by dedicated enthusiasts. Impedance matching delivers power as efficiently as possible into the resonator - no power is lost in the capacitive component of the antenna, just transferred along  the circuit.

Comment: Again Thanks alot @glen_geek. Please do not die of Corona or anything else. It seems that world has to learn alot from you.

Answer (score 2):

The LC circuit exists to select the AM station in this corcuit here. These devices are intended to be connected to an antenna large enough to pick up significant AM signal (there is no amplification, the only power source is the received signal itself). Also the earpiece should be very high impedance in order to efficiently convert the tiny signal into sound.

You can't really know from the diagram what the voltage out is. It's just a filtered (frequency selected) version of the signal picked up on the antenna. Without it, you should hear wideband noise, with any transmitted signals probably lost in the noise.

The voltage across the speaker is just the voltage available on the (loaded) antenna (which depends on received signal strength and the antenna itself), half-rectified, filtered according to the characteristics of the tank circuit, and less a diode drop.

Comment: Yes you are right. So how can we get the amplitude of the AM signal? @danmcb

Comment: And that amplitude of the signal is also the amplitude of the voltage from the LC circuit to the source. Am I right?

Comment: it's whatever is picked up on the (loaded) antenna, but half-rectified and less a diode drop. Actually that should have been in my answer - I'll add it.